# encoding both rank and suit of a card into a single integer value

Tags: c++

So I have to basically encode both the rank and suit of a card into a single integer value. So for instance, I have to make it say "Seven of Hearts" instead of just "7" into a card game I am making.

```
enum Suit {Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, Spades};
enum Rank {A, K, Q, J, _10, _9, _8, _7, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2};
```

so i have that now. I just put them into enum. I'm not sure if it would work though. How would I somehow basically combine those 2 strings into a single integer value? So like, I need to make it so it says "Seven of Hearts". Would I need a for loop to combine them?

Comment: There are 52 cards, and 52 numbers in the range [0, 51]. Can you come up with a one-to-one mapping between a card and a number? Forget about C++ for a second, how would you do this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to. You're not going to save much space by combining into one integer.
Just create a struct to represent a card:

```
struct card {
    Suit m_suit;
    Rank m_rank;
};
```

If you really want to combine into an integer (or just to learn how to do it), you can use low 16 bits of an integer to store the suit, and high 16 bits for rank. This assumes int is 32 bits of course:

```
int card_from_rank_and_suit(Suit suit, Rank rank)
{
    return ((int)suit) & ((int)rank << 16);
}
```

and to read back the suit and rank value:
    Suit suit_from_card(int card)
    {
        return (Suit) (card & 0x0000ffff);
    }

```
Rank rank_from_card(int card)
{
    return (Rank) ((card & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned to use structs or classes yet though. Would I be able to combine the enums into one array instead?

Comment: If you are learning C++ you should learn to use structs and classes. Even for C you want to learn to use structs anyway. It's an essential part of the language.

Comment: You can easily combine the two values in just 8 bits; no need to put in a non-portable assumption that `int` is at least 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could use different bit positions within an int to represent the 2 parts. For example, you could make the low 2 bits be the suit and the remaining bits be the card value. A function to get the full card name from an integer argument named `cardValue` might contain the following:

```
Suit theSuit = cardValue & 0x03;
Rank theRank = cardValue >> 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in single byte. Since there are four possibility for Rank, and 13 possibility for card: for example

reserve first nibble in byte for Rank and 
reserve second nibble in byte for Card.

```
Say: 0x1 << 0 = Hearts, 
     0x1 << 1 = Diamonds, 
     0x1 << 2 = Clubs, 
     0x1 << 3 = Spades.
```

second nibble for Card: Since there are 13 possibility, represent them by number from 0x0 to 0xD.

```
 For example:
              ox1 = A, o2 = 2, ox3 = 3, and so on.
```

So complete picture will be look a like:

```
For Seven of heart:    0001, 0111(0x17)
For Three of Diamonds: 0010, 0011(0x23)
```